# Materials tab missing

Tags: materials

[image: Materials tab missing]

I am working on blender using a friend's computer, and I cannot find the materials tab. I circled the red area where it is usually located for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's there, but it's hidden because the properties editor is not wide enough.

You need to either

- Scroll the header over a bit by clicking and dragging on the tabs with <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd>.

or

- Expand the *Properties editor* by clicking and dragging on the boundary between the properties editor and the 3D view.

Example:

[image]