# Texture tab/properties panel missing 2.82/2.91

Tags: texturing, properties, panel

Texture tab/properties panel is missing.
When I open a new file, it's there. It's definitely something to do with the file, because it's the same story after opening this file in 2.91 and 2.82. Also moved from cycles to evee and that didn't trigger it back as it was suggested on other posts.

[image]

Found these similar questions and answers which unfortunately didn't work:
[Texture tab seemingly missing in Blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169024/texture-tab-seemingly-missing-in-blender-2-8)

> Object mode doesn't bring back the texture tab for me.

[Materials tab missing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18721/materials-tab-missing)

> Applicable for older versions.

[modifier tab missing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75625/modifier-tab-missing)

> Looked here for insights too. Definitely using a solid shape to apply the texture to rather than an empty.

This could be a really basic and silly solution - but I'd appreciate learning from it.

Comment: Yeah, that's weird - I cannot recreate the problem as the Texture Properties tab is always there for me (in object mode), even if I remove all objects and materials from the scene, delete all brushes, and clear the orphaned data. Strange indeed...

Comment: Just as a test, try entering Texture Paint mode and then switch back to Object mode and see if that makes the tab appear.

Comment: Oh wow! It appears in Texture Paint mode (woohoo! Thank you!)
When I switch back to other modes it disappears again. At least I can still access it in the meantime.

Comment: It's actually appearing in every single other mode except the Modelling mode. Perhaps I've somehow removed it from the Modelling mode.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know. I got the idea from this ticket - https://developer.blender.org/T73611 - It seems even the people in the discussion can't decide if it's a bug or not.

Comment: And all of a sudden it's re appeared in the modelling mode as well. 
Thank you for the suggestion and the reference link, I'll follow it as well.